# Excellent review/introduction for a future grad student in need

Tags: reference-request, self-learning

I recently graduated with a computer engineering degree and am now going to study neuroscience/neuro-engineering at the graduate level. I need to beef up on my linear algebra, differential equations, numerical analysis, and statistical analysis (bayes what?!). As such, I would like to ask what are some excellent books I could purchase that would help me in this regard? Since I'm doing self learning, examples are important, and preferably it would make use of Matlab since I would like to learn that as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Update: I've added the following books to my list:

- [Matlab for Neuroscientists​: An Introduction to Scientific Computing in Matlab](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123745519)
- [Concrete Mathematics: A Foundation for Computer Science (2nd Edition)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201558025)
- [All the Mathematics You Missed: But Need to Know for Graduate School](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521792851)
- [A Modern Introduction to Differential Equations, Second Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123747465)
- [Linear Algebra: A Modern Introduction](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0538735457)

But I'm still looking for more!

Comment: I voted you over the new user restrictions threshold, so you should now be able to post the links.

Comment: much obliged Theo

Comment: The "All the mathematics you need..." book, if I recall correctly, is more intended for Graduate Students _in mathematics_. I'm a bit doubtful about its practical use for you.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of differential equations, you may be capable of just jumping right in with a book like *Foundations of Mathematical Neuroscience* by Ermentrout and Terman. The beginning chapters don't require much more than basic calculus.

Answer (score 1):

For Linear Algebra I highly recommend Glibert Strang's MIT OCW and his book. Both of which are absolutely amazing.